# How raise ObservableArray.changeEvent using notify()

Tags: nativescript

Some properties of Repeater items in XML are binded to methods (I can't make getters for them, only methods):

```
<Repeater items="{{ some.items }}">
    <Repeater.itemsLayout>
        <StackLayout/>
    </Repeater.itemsLayout>
    <Repeater.itemTemplate>
        <Button tap="{{ onTap }}" text="{{ getText() }}" backgroundColor="{{ getButtonBg() }}"/>
    </Repeater.itemTemplate>
</Repeater>
```

All works. But now I want `getButtonBg()` for each Button in Repeater was recalculated, although `some.buttons` was not changed.
I try different ways raise different events via `notify()`, but can't force `getButtonBg()` to be called.
I don't want do dummy `some.items.setItem(0, some.items.getItem(0)`. It works. But I want get same effect via `notify()`

Comment: If you just want to raise property change event, use `observable.notifyPropertyChange("propertyName", newValue)`

Comment: @Manoj which property? I use methods.

Comment: If you want to update specific properties of an item in ObservableArray and UI to be notified, use Observable instead of simple object inside the Array. So when you calculate and update backgroundColor it will be immediately notified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`notify()` method of `some.items` must be called with `object` referencing to the same `ObservableArray`

```
this.some.items.notify({
    eventName: ObservableArray.changeEvent,
    object: this.some.items
});
```